# Prompt the user for filename when doing Data tables export to excel

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to export the jQuery data tables to excel,in that i want to ask the user for the filename when Export button is clicked and download the file once filename is entered.

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
    buttons: [
        {
            extend: 'excel',
            "text":'Excel <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>',
            className: 'btn btn-success',
            filename: 'fixed_file_name'
        }   
    ]
});
```

Currently if i add function for getting filename,first the file is downloaded and then the function is getting executed.like below

```
filename: function(){
return prompt('Please enter file name');
}
```

I want to call a function which prompts the user for entering the filename and once the user enters the filename it should be assigned to filename data attribute.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To dynamically chnage filename, refer [**this**](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/32512/dynamically-change-filename-when-exporting), which you are already referring.

But inside function, you want to prompt to enter something, and want to return that . then you can use something like below :

```
filename: function(){
    var filename = prompt("Please enter your file name", "");
    if (filename != null) {
        return filename;
    }
}
```

**Edit:**

looks like you had some other issue with your datatable.
I also implement the same, and above solution works for me fine.

See **[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yashsoni789/4tuupc5f/1266/)**

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I already tried that, that prompt will be popped up on page load, not on Export button click.

Comment: are you using it with serverside or clientside?

Comment: Client side, jQuery datatables.

Comment: @raviraja , I updated my answer. looks like you have some other issue. It's not happening with me. See working demo is Jsfiddle.